# How to have automatic update of gradle dependencies by using a defined file for dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle

In my project, I have a `dependencies.gradle` file. In this one, I have differents arrays of dependencies with corresponding version.

I would like to know if is there a way to have automatic update available version for dependency with this way ?

For example, if i declare `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2` in build.gradle directly, it'll tell me that a new version is available. Actually, it's declared in my `dependencies.gradle` like this :

`appCompat       : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$appCompatVersion"`

and the version is in the same file, define above like this : `appCompatVersion = "27.0.2"`

Android Studio doesn't tell me that a new version is available. I'm looking on internet but didn't find anything. Does any one know how I can proceed to achieve this ?

Comment: before giving -1 please think that we are here to help, not to do anything else ..... https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Comment: i added   :+  .... it will update the whole version, thats why answering sometimes here is not very welcome by the community

Answer (score 0):

In your Project build.gradle, define the version :

```
ext {
    appCompatVersion = '27.0.2'
}
```

Then in your module build.gradle, you can use it :

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
}
```

And Android Studio will inform you when updates are available !

[image: Android studio warnings]

Comment: Thank you man, but my dependencies are not defined in the build.gradle file, they are in an other file, as explained above

Comment: This is part of the problem, All I want to do is alt+enter and voila... updating!!!